# Is there a module that displays a RSS feed as horizontally scrolling text?

Tags: 7

Is there an equivalent of the [ScrollText](https://drupal.org/project/scrolltext) module that takes text from a RSS feed and shows it as horizontally scrolling text?

The purpose of the ScrollText is showing text taken from node titles as horizontally scrolling text.

[image: screenshot]

What I am looking for is a module that does the same, but with text taken from a RSS feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean like a ticker, similar to what news sites have, then you can use the [Views Ticker](https://drupal.org/project/views_ticker) module.

> This module provides new styles for Views module to display news tickers. A comparison of similar modules is available here: http://drupal.org/node/418616.
>
> Available ticker styles:
>
> - Fade: Smooth transition between news titles, light and JQuery-powered
> - BBC Style: Display news titles typewriter-like (Only links)
> - Scroller: Display horizontally or vertically scrolling news titles
> - vTicker: jQuery based Vertical scrolling lines with options: pause time, speed, direction, items displayed
> - liScroller: jQuery based Horizontal scrolling lines with options Direction and Speed

Comment: This is very interesting, but I think the news items here are nodes that belong to the news site itself and not an RSS item coming from another site - don't you think so. Take [this site](http://file54.com/sbdc) for example; have a look at the second white ribboned scroll bar. It is bringing items from twitter or any other site with an RSS service.